# How to convert a PDF file to a LibreOffice(ODT, ODS, ODP) file in PHP?

Tags: php, libreoffice, phpword, odt, ods

I am currently using PHPWord and I am wondering if there is a way to convert a PDF file to LibreOffice(ODT, ODS, ODP)?

**Here is the code I used to convert a .DOC file to .DOCX with PHPWord:**

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory as WordIOFactory;

$phpWord = WordIOFactory::load('test/example.doc', 'MsDoc');
$phpWord->save('test.docx');
```

**Can you help me to convert a PDF file to a LibreOffice(ODT, ODS, ODP) file in PHP?**

Comment: Can PHPWORD do this? Or can you give me an idea or suggest a library that can do it?

Comment: @k-j I don't really understand what you are telling me to do to myself. Can you write more clearly or give me an example please?

Comment: @k-j I'm beginning to understand. If I have a docx file, is it possible to convert it to ODP, ODS AND ODT? If so, what do you recommend I do to convert it?

Comment: There is the CloudConvert API, that is able to convert files into other formats. DOCX to ODP is also supported. https://cloudconvert.com/apis/pdf-to-office

Comment: @k-j And then what do you advise me to use to transform docx into odp, ods and odt please?

Comment: @odan is paid and I just want to use a free library that will give me the ability to convert a docx file to odt, ods and odp.

Comment: @k-j Can you send me the link to libreoffice?